# react-select handle onChange with props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I am using react-select in a child component but wanting to store the Select value in a state in the parent.

I appreciate that I have to store onChange in state and then pass this to the Select value, but I would like to keep this temporary onChange state in the child component not the parent.

So the question is how do I set the parent state (coming in on a prop) from the onChange state in the child.

**Parent Component**

```
campaignName (campaign){
  //will setState here
   console.log(campaign)
  }
...
<FormGroup>
  <Campaign
    campaignName={this.campaignName.bind(this)}
    campaignOptions={code in here that sets option}
   />
</FormGroup>
```

**Child Component**

```
updateValue (newValue) {
    this.setState({
        selectValue: newValue,
  // how do I set the parent state from this 
    });

<Select
   onChange={this.updateValue}
   value={this.props.campaignName}
   options={this.props.campaignOptions}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the function directly from parent to child that will handle the onChange:

**Parent Component**

```
handleSelect(e) {
   this.setState({
       selectValue: e.target.value,
   });
}

render() {
    <ChildComponent selectOnChange={this.handleSelect} />
}
```

**Child Component**

```
<Select
   onChange={this.props.selectOnChange}
   value={this.props.campaignName}
/>
```

OR (if you want the method to stay on the child)

```
updateValue(e) {
   this.props.selectOnChange(e); //call the passed props here
}

<Select
   onChange={this.updateValue}
   value={this.props.campaignName}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was exploring how to store the onChange in the child not passing in from the parent

Comment: I've updated my answer, I added another option to solve your problem.

Comment: Don't forget to mark it as the correct answer if it solves your problem so the other with the same problem can refer to this question. Thank you :)

Comment: Thanks Will do Tenten I am just working through it now

Comment: There is no selectOnChange prop from the parent there is only the campaignName. The way I understand react-select works is the onChange prop is stored in state (e.g. selectValue) which the value prop then uses. When I try replacing your selectOnChange with campaignName I get an undefined error

Comment: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/examples/src/components/States.js

Comment: Can you show the code of your Parent Component? I don't understand why you can't add another attribute to be passed as props on the child (selectOnChange is just a variable). By the way, you can change the (e) to selectValue if that's the case on react-select :) 

(My example is generic for default select)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160588/discussion-between-nick-wild-and-tenten-ponce).